# Answering your own questions to create a reference

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I’ve seen a few questions which I consider to be off to a bad start — how to do something which should have been done differently in the first place.

For example, on Stack Overflow there are many questions that involve PHP and databases, but they overlook the fundamental risk of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), so the user needs to learn more before proceeding.

I would like to be able to point to a simple explanation of the risks and the processes.

The question is: is it appropriate to ask and answer my own question to create such a reference? Are there any good examples of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fine to answer your own question if you have the best answer to it. From this [post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/):

> if you have a question that you already know the answer to
>
> if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself)
>   can find it later
>
> it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack
>   Exchange site. To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and
>   answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.

But beware there are already many reference type questions there, so chances are your canonical may become a duplicate of an already answered Q&A.

Instead, first search for them and try to contribute to them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also good advice about checking first.